data state is not updating even with useEffect hook
I am new to reactjs anet td I have stocks app that shows the price of crypto currencies. My issue is I want to update the state in real time without refreshing the page. I tried to use useEffect but it is not working. I used a custom hook to fetch the data and the hook is used in other pages one of them is the quote page for crypto currencies. I want this, when the user input searched, then the result should be updating the price that is showing in the page as in realtime changes. The result for not is ok, after I search the input word, I get the result but if the state changes in the server, I can't see the change on the result I searched. I hope this is clear, thank you in advance.
This is my Search page where I want the price to be updating in realtime.
import SearchInput from "../components/SearchInput";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../../src/App.css";
import useFetch from "../Hooks/useFetch";
import useDataApi from "../Hooks/axisFetch";
import ArrowDownward from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowDownward";
import ArrowUpward from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowUpward";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { auth, db } from "../auth/auth";
import { addDoc, collection, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useUserAuth } from "../auth/UserAuthContent";
import Star from "@mui/icons-material/Star";

const Search = () => {
  const { user } = useUserAuth(auth);
  const apiUrl = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote/";
  const [query, setQuery] = useState([]);
  const [{ data, isLoading, isError }, doFetch] = useDataApi(
    `${apiUrl}/BTCUSD?apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
  );

  const sendSymbol = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (query.trim() === "") {
      alert("Enter valid message");
      return;
    }
    const { uid, displayName } = auth.currentUser;
    await addDoc(collection(db, "stocksSymbol"), {
      text: query,
      name: displayName,
      createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
      uid,
    });
    setQuery("");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    
  }, [data, isLoading, isError, query, doFetch, useDataApi]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <h1 className="header"> CRYPTO CURRENCIES SEARCH</h1>
      <h3>You can search by company name, compnay stock shortcut</h3>

      <form
        onSubmit={(event) => {
          doFetch(
            `${apiUrl}${[query]}?apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
          );
          event.preventDefault();
        }}
      >
        <SearchInput
          type="text"
          value={query}
          onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)}
        />
        <Button variant="contained" size="small" type="submit">
          Search
        </Button>
      </form>

      {/* <SearchInput
        type="text"
        value={text}
        onChange={handleChange}
      /> */}

      <div className="listContainer">
        <ul className="list">
          {isError && <div>Something went wrong ...</div>}
          {isLoading ? (
            <div>Loading ...</div>
          ) : (
            <>
              {data &&
                data.map((item) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={item.id}>
                      <span>{item.symbol}</span>
                      **<span>{item.price}</span>**
                      <span>{item.name}</span>
                      <span> % {item.change}</span>
                      <>
                        {item.change < 0 ? (
                          <ArrowDownward style={{ color: "red" }} />
                        ) : (
                          <ArrowUpward />
                        )}
                      </>
                      {!user ? (
                        ""
                      ) : (
                        <button
                          style={{
                            border: "none",
                            background: "none",
                            color: "yellow",
                          }}
                          onClick={(event) => sendSymbol(event)}
                        >
                          <Star />
                        </button>
                      )}
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
            </>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Search;

This is my custom hook
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

const useDataApi = (initialUrl, initialData) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsError(false);
      setIsLoading(true);

      try {
        const result = await axios(url);

        setData(result.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(true);
      }

      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  return [{ data, isLoading, isError }, setUrl];
};

export default useDataApi;


`useEffect(() => {
}, [data, isLoading, isError, query, doFetch, useDataApi]);doesn't do anything.  The callback is() => {}`  I assume that's not intentional...

I tried to use it in different ways but it did not fire. I left it there by a mistake.
